# When a matrix is neither negative semidefinite, nor positive semidefinite, nor indefinite? (Only with Real numbers)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the book Calculus by Robert Adams, when the author introduces the Hessian Matrix in order to classify the critical points of a function, it says that: $\textit{If the Hessian matrix is neither negative semidefinite, nor positive semidefinite, nor indefinite}$ then the second derivative test with the Hessian Matrix can't classify the critical point.

So my question is What kind of matrix is not positive, nor negative nor indefinite?

The only matrix it comes to my mind is the zero matrix, but I don't know if is the only one.

Thanks.

Comment: Does $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ works for you? Also the zero matrix is indefinite

Comment: But that matrix that you say is indefinite right? And why the zero matrix is indefinite?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but indefinite means not definite, thus there exists $x\neq 0$ such that ${}^t \! x A x = 0$. This one is neither positive semi-def nor negative semi-def nor indefinite

Comment: The kind of matrix you are looking for is any matrix with at least one zero, at least one positive and at least one negative eigenvalue, for example the diagonal matrix with diagonal $(1,0,-1)$. Note that in your context "indefinite" means that it has only positive and negative eigenvalues (or in other words the determinant is not $0$).

Comment: The author is most likely using some non-standard definition of indefinite matrix.

Comment: The author uses the standard definition of an indefinite matrix.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the 7th edition of Adams' "Calculus: A Complete Course" it says in theorem 3 on page 747 ($\mathcal{H}(a)$ is the Hessian evaluated at $a$, a critical point of the function):

"If $\mathcal{H}(a)$ is neither positive nor negative definite nor indefinite, this test gives no information."

This differs importantly from your version (which has "semidefinite" instead of "definite").

An indefinite matrix is one that is neither positive semi-definite nor negative semi-definite. So, a matrix that is "neither positive nor negative definite nor indefinite" is positive or negative semi-definite. (The only matrix that is both positive and negative semi-definite is the zero matrix.)

For example, the function $f$ given by $f(x)=x^4$ has a stationary point at $x=0$. At that point the Hessian is zero and so negative and positive semi-definite. The second-derivative test is inconclusive.